# Haystack with Solr's clustering component (carrot2)

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, carrot2

I have Solr configured to do carrot2's STC clustering component (Solr 6) and can access results with the requestHandler=/clustering via Solr's web interface.   However, we are using Haystack/Django (1.10) to access Solr and I cannot find anything online that indicates support in Haystack for this.  Is it possible? If so, how?